# Retrieving MySql Queries to JSON in Sencha Architect - how?

Tags: mysql, json, extjs, sencha-architect

I have followed several EXTJS + PHP + MYSQL tutorials (for normal EXTJS, not for Sencha Architect) and somehow I am still confused on retrieving MySql Queries to JSON in Sencha Architect. The thing is this Sencha Architect pretty much generates and overrides all the codes so I have a bit of trouble trying to imitate things from the available tutorials.

Currently, I want to know the process of the following:

1. Where is the part in Sencha Architect that I can request for MySql queries?
2. Is conversion for MySql to JSON in Architect automatic? Or must I need something else?

PS: could somebody add "Sencha Architect" tag for this question?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a store
2. Create a model
3. Add said model to said store
4. Configure the url of the proxy to the url ur generating ur json at.
5. Set autoload on the store
6. Right click on the store in architect and press Load data to check that the store gets populated
7. Profit???

Answer (score 0):

Sencha Architect is mainly for easy creation of extjs components and UI side of your application not the backend.

If you need to retrieve json from the server set up urls and then configure that in your architect while defining stores and ajax requests.